B R Chopra Mahabharat
This question is to the people belongs to 55+ age, regarding the BR Chopra Mahabharat,why they haven't raised an objection of choosing a person of dark complexion to play a role of Krishna,are they not aware the meaning of Krishna and complexion of the same.

Most Indians prefer fair skin. Krishna is depicted as being akin to a dark raincloud in the scriptures, but no one has that complexion since He's truly perceived in meditation alone by the yogis. Casting someone darker would have been nice however Krishna's instructions are more important in a TV show meant for the masses and anyways no one can portray Krishna's beauty which is not material / completely spiritual in nature. One can only get an idea through the Shastras.

Kṛṣṇa Dvaipāyana, Kṛṣṇa, Arjuna and Draupadī, all these had kṛṣṇa varṇa, yet entertainment industry rarely pays attention to this aspect when making series on Mahābhārata. At least in BR Chopra's version, the complexion of Kṛṣṇa is shown to be a bit darker, if you notice clearly.
The Indian obsession (more in North) with fair skin is well known, this came into vogue primarily during the colonial period and has prevailed since then.

In pre-colonial period, both fair and dark complexions were seen as beautiful. As for whether the makers of BR Chopra's serial Mahābhārata  were aware of Draupadī, etc. having darker complexions, not known. But even if they knew, they still didn't take much care in this aspect.
